# Adding gap between columns in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Check out [this](http://fortrex.malcolmtanti.com/test) site

On the slider I have 4 columns which say text inside them, right?

I want gaps between those columns like below.

███████████ ███████████  ███████████  ███████████

I saw many posts on Stackoverflow about how to do this. But they don't work for me.

Any help please?

HTML:

```
<div id="rowCopy">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3" id="box">Text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3" id="box"><img width="100%" src="./images/datamanagement.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3" id="box"><img width="100%" src="./images/storageservices.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3" id="box"><img width="100%" src="./images/storageservices.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content #rowCopy{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#content #rowCopy #box {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 17px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.82);
    margin: 10px;
    padding:0;
    top: -40px;
}
```

Comment: have you tried margins or paddings?

Comment: Please show your codes in your questions.

Comment: **Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows.** from [Official CSS Bootstrap Introduction](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro), you should probably alter the padding manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css

```
#content #rowCopy #box {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 17px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.82);
    margin: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    top: -40px;
}

.col-sm-3 {
    width: 22%;
}
```

Comment: Indeed it did, Could you explain why you added this:                                background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;

Comment: I din't add the background property. But it was added by the browser while rendering your css code. Read more on [background](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) property